# Append img using src from another page

Tags: jquery

I have a set of thumnails generated by cms. These are linked to a popup window containing the full image. What I want to do is use jquery to get the full images to populate a lazy-loading slider.

So basically I'm just going through each thumbnail, getting it's link destination, then finding the full image there.

At the moment, the only way I have been able to get it to work is to keep checking it until it's finished.

I've just realized this doesn't work as intended because it's loading the images to get the src, which makes lazy loading pointless... Is there any solution to this?

```
$('.thumbnails img').each(function() {
  var large = $(this).parent().attr('href');
  $.get(large, function(data) {
    var imgs = $('<div/>').html(data).find('img');
    var src = "";
    imgs.each(function(i, img) {
      src = (img.src);
    });
    $('.slider').append('<div><img data-lazy="' + src + '"/></div>');
  });
});

var checkExist = setInterval(function() {
if($('.slider').find('img').length == $('.thumbnails').find('img').length){
  $('.slider').slick({
    lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
  });
  clearInterval(checkExist);
 };
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I was doing it all wrong because $get() would load all the images early. Instead I reworked it to use blank img tags until the slide is needed. This way the slider has content to initialize with and I am lazy-loading manually.

```
//Make a list of all the urls and fill slider with blank images
var large = [];
$('.thumbnails img').each(function() {
  $('.slider').append('<img src=""/>');
  large.push($(this).parent().attr('href'));
  $(this).parent().attr("href", "javascript:;");
  $(this).parent().removeAttr("onclick").removeAttr("target");
});

//Set the first image src
$.get(large[0], function(data) {
  var imgs = $('<div/>').html(data).find('img');
  imgs.each(function(i, img) {
    var src = (img.src);
    $('.slider img').first().attr('src', src);
  });   
});

//Initialize Slider
$('.slider').slick();

//When the slider changes set the src for the next slide image
$('.slider').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  $.get(large[nextSlide], function(data) {
    var imgs = $('<div/>').html(data).find('img');
    imgs.each(function(i, img) {
      var src = (img.src);
      $('.slick-slide').eq(nextSlide).find('img').attr('src', src);
    });   
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  var length = $('.thumbnails img').length;
    $('.thumbnails img').each(function(index, item) {
      var large = $(this).parent().attr('href');
      $.get(large, function(data) {
        var imgs = $('<div/>').html(data).find('img');
        var src = "";
        imgs.each(function(i, img) {
           src = (img.src);
        if (index == length - 1) {   //last item
           $('.slider').append('<div><img data-lazy="' + src + '"/></div>');
      }
        });
       $('.slider').slick({
    lazyLoad: 'ondemand'
  });
      });
```

Comment: This works but the slider is initializing before the images are appended. Do you know how to fix?

Comment: put the slider initialization after adding the images (inside the ajax get). check the edited answer.

Comment: The problem with that is it initializes after the first image, and it needs to happen after all images are done.

Comment: @user500665 you got it wrong. put it after the `img.each` function ends that would be after all images appended.

Comment: You misunderstand, there is only one image per $get  - so the initialization would have to come after the $('.thumbnails img').each

Comment: @user500665 yep now I get it. I corrected the answer.

Comment: Sorry, this only adds the last image and still initializes too early...